# Shrinking html items to match screen-size?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a page that includes a large vertical form and I need it to be resized depending on the screen size. I want the form inputs to shrink with adequate margins on both the left and right side. My css consists of code like:

```
.container-register input#search, select {
width: 300px;
}
```

This makes the initial input widths fairly long so I have tried using @media (max-width) scripts to change the length but it looks very hardcoded. I want it to seamlessly change depending on the viewport without me having to use these @media scripts for every possible viewport width. I was thinking maybe something like flex? However I was having trouble using it.

```
 <div class="body-content-register">
  <div class="wrapper">

<center><section id="bg" class="zoom-register">
        <div class="box-register">
          <center><h1>Register</h1></center>
          <form class="register">
          <div class="container-register">
            <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
            <input type="search" name="fullname" id="search" placeholder="Full Name">


          </div><br><br><br><br>

      <div class="container-register">
        <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i></span>
        <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Email">

      </div><br><br><br><br>

            <div class="container-register">
                <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Username">
            </div><br><br><br><br>

            <div class="container-register">
                <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-birthday-cake"></i></span>
                <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Date of Birth">
            </div><br><br><br><br>

            <div class="container-register">
                <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></span>
                <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Postcode">
            </div><br><br><br><br>

            <div class="container-register">
                <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>
                <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Password">
            </div><br><br><br><br>

            <div class="container-register">
                <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>
                <input type="search" id="search" placeholder="Confirm Password">
            </div><br><br><br><br>

            <div class="float-middle">

                <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="checkbox"> Do you accept our terms & conditions?<br>
            </div><br>

            <button class="button"><strong>Submit</strong></button>

    </form>
    </div>
  </section></center>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Typically you'd just use a few media queries for standard devices. You should only need one or two queries based on your desired look for mobile / tablet / laptop / desktop. I'd hardly say that was excessively hardcoded. Just decide on how much spacing you want at X breakpoints, and add media queries for each of those breakpoints.

Comment: Oh that is true! It's a habit to resize on my browser and expect those results as the optimal outcome haha. But what if someone views it on a laptop at a different resolution? Because for example someone could view the website on half their screen which would be very custom.

Comment: Media queries are based on the **browser** width, not the screen width. That is to say, if you're on a desktop, and drag your pane so that it is narrow, you will be presented with the same media query that you would get on a mobile device (as an example). As such, you typically build media queries to 'correct' behaviour such as long bits of text being cut off at small widths. It's **very** rare to need / want vertical media queries, and normally you'd just have the same amount of space between elements at different screen widths. Don't forget that mobiles can scroll too :)

Answer (score 0):

Besides using media queries you can use **[intrinsic units of measurement like `vw` and `vh`](http://thenewcode.com/660/Using-vw-and-vh-Measurements-In-Modern-Site-Design)**. Not related to the question but I feel I should point out that `#ID` must be unique so you can't have every element have `id='search'`. The `type` attribute of an `<input>` determines its behavior so `type="search"` isn't really what you need. Also there are **[more suitable tags](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/How_to_structure_an_HTML_form)** that you could use other than `<div>` and `<span>`, but that's purely optional. I changed the layout a bit to reflect what I previously mentioned.

#### Demo

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 2vw 2vh;
}

h3 {
  margin: 0
}

.line {
  border: 0;
  width: 96vw;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

i {
  width: 3vw;
  margin: 0 1vw 0 0;
}

.name {
  display: block
}

#fullName {
  width: 86vw;
}

input {
  font: inherit;
  width: 39vw;
}

.DOB input {
  width: 12vw;
  text-align: center;
}

.disclosure {
  display: block;
  margin: 2vh auto 0;
  width: 80vw;
}

#accept {
  width: 3vw;
}

[type=submit] {
  width: 16vw
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<main>
  <form id='register'>
    <fieldset id="bg">
      <legend>
        <h3>
          Register
        </h3>
      </legend>
      <label class="icon name"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>
            <input type="text" id="fullName" name="fullName" placeholder="Full Name"></label>
      <fieldset class='line'>
        <label class="icon email"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"></label>

        <label class="icon user"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                <input type="text" id="userName" name="userName" placeholder="Username"></label>
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset class='line'>
        <label class='icon DOB'> <i class="fa fa-birthday-cake"></i>
                <input type="number" id="DOBmonth" name="DOBmonth" placeholder="Month" min='1' max='12'>
                <input type="number" id="DOBday" name="DOBday" placeholder="Day" min='1' max='31'>
                <input type="number" id="DOByear" name="DOByear" placeholder="Year" min='1900' max='2000'></label>

        <label class="icon country"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                <input type="text" id="country" name='country' placeholder="Country"></label>
      </fieldset>

      <label class="icon pass"><i class="fa fa-key"></i>
                <input type="password" id="pass" placeholder="Password">

              
                <input type="password" id="confirm" placeholder="Confirm Password">
            </label>
    </fieldset>
    <label class='disclosure'>
    <input type="checkbox" id='accept' name="accept" value="accept"> Do you accept our terms &amp; conditions?
    <input type="submit"></label>
  </form>
</main>
```